# How do I use spark xml data source in .net?

Tags: apache-spark, .net-core

Is there a way to use spark-xml (https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) in a spark .net/c# job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use spark-xml data source from .Net. 
Here is the test program:

```
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql;

    namespace MySparkApp
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .Builder()
                    .AppName("spark-xml-example")
                    .GetOrCreate();

                DataFrame df = spark.Read()
                    .Option("rowTag", "book")
                    .Format("xml")
                    .Load("books.xml");
                df.Show();

                df.Select("author", "_id")
                    .Write()
                    .Format("xml")
                    .Option("rootTag", "books")
                    .Option("rowTag", "book")
                    .Save("newbooks.xml");
                spark.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Checkout https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml and build an assembly jar using 'sbt assembly' command, copy the assembly jar to the dotnet project workspace.

Build project: dotnet build

Submit Spark job:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner \
--jars scala-2.11/spark-xml-assembly-0.10.0.jar \
--master local bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/microsoft-spark-2.4.x-0.10.0.jar \
dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/sparkxml.dll
```